# Youtube HTML5 Video Stopped Working in Android

Tags: java, android, youtube

Somehow Youtube HTML5 video stopped working for me about a week ago. I have no idea why. Here's the code that was working last week (well, not the real code, but the smallest example I could make):

```
public class VideoTestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.OFF);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new TestWebChromeClient());

        setContentView(webView);

        // Try with http://player.vimeo.com/video/24158845 and it works.
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/e2UIg3Ddfp0");
    }

    private class TestWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback) {
            super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
            VideoTestActivity.this.setContentView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work on my phone or the emulator. The crazy part is that Vimeo still works great. I tried setting an iPhone user agent, but that didn't work and I'm out of ideas. It really looks like Youtube has changed something...

Comment: i have worked last night on this with no luck.. it is weird.. I was able to get youtube with the default control but still seems that there is a js error somewhere,

Comment: btw the above code seems to be working now. Assume that Google has fixed the javascript error

Comment: Yes, they did exactly this, so this is all a non-issue again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Youtube` may have changed something in their embedded page and most likely this is causing problems inside the `WebView` and that is why it is not working anymore.

Also are you testing your app on the same device as before?

I don't think it is a good practice to use this solution, since you can not rely that the content that you display today from `Youtube` and it works, will also be the same in a few days and it will still work, as you have just encountered now. I had also similar problems with `videos` and `Youtube` content, it would work on one device, and not at all on some other devices. It is also a `Flash` content, and a lot of Android devices don't have `Flash` and will not be able to play the content.

A solution would be to create an `Intent` for playing the video:

```
      Intent videoIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                                     Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/my_url"));
      startActivity(videoIntent);
```

But what I would recommend is to encode the videos for `Android` as suggested in the [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) and store them on your own server if you have the possibility.

**EDIT:** They definetly changed something since there is an js error there. You can track them by using the `WebChromeClient`:

```
  mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber,
                String sourceID) {
            super.onConsoleMessage(message, lineNumber, sourceID);
            Log.i("VIDEO VIEW",message);
        }
 }
```

This is the message error I got:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'a' [undefined] is not an object.line 78sourcehttp://www.youtube.com/embed/e2UIg3Ddfp0
```

I don't know if it helps you, I'll have another look later and see what I can find.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I never though about listening for JS errors. The entire point of the app is to watch video, mostly from Youtube, so I guess if this never gets fixed on Youtube's side I'll have to see if I can intercept the source somehow and fix it, or use an intent. The intent solution is a bit sucky because it takes people to a new app and makes them choose between the browser and the Youtube app, but, if it's the only option, I guess that's all you can do.